# Initializing a Swift array with UIImageView repeatedValue() does not seem to work

Tags: ios, arrays, uiview, uiimageview, initialization

I am trying to create a 5 `UIImageView` programmatically, add them in a row as subviews in `init(frame:)` method of parent `UIView`. When I run the code, only the last image view shows up. First 4 are missing.

I am initializing an array of `UIImageView` using `repeatedValue:`.
Is this a proper use of the initialization method?

**This is the code I am using:**

import UIKit

```
class DistanceView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    print("init frame called")

    let distances = [UIImageView](count: 5, repeatedValue: UIImageView())
    distances[0].image=UIImage(named: "1")
    distances[1].image=UIImage(named: "2")
    distances[2].image=UIImage(named: "3")
    distances[3].image=UIImage(named: "4")
    distances[4].image=UIImage(named: "5")

    for var i = 0; i<5; i++ {
        distances[i].frame=CGRectMake(0+CGFloat(i)*frame.width*0.1, 0, 0.06*frame.width, 0.06*frame.width*1.6377)
        self.addSubview(distances[i])

    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    print("init coder called")

    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Beware of `repeatedValue`**

The *value* every element in a Swift array initialized with `repeatedValue()` is identical.

**Intermediate array**

```swift
var distances = [UIImageView]()
for i in 1...5 {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image\(i)"))
    distances.append(imageView)
}

for i in 0 ..< distances.count {
    distances[i].frame =
        CGRectMake(0+CGFloat(i)*frame.width*0.1, 0,
        0.06*frame.width, 0.06*frame.width*1.6377)
    self.addSubview(distances[i])
}
```

**No intermediate array**

You may not need to cache your `UIImageView` in a separate array in the first place. You could even iterate using `.subviews` after the `addSubview` phase.

```swift
for i in 0...4 {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage( named: "image\(1+i)"))
    imageView.frame =
        CGRectMake(0+CGFloat(i)*frame.width*0.1, 0,
        0.06*frame.width, 0.06*frame.width*1.6377)
    self.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

---

You are initializing your array with `n` times the same value. You are creating a single repeated `UIImageView`.

```
let distances = [UIImageView](count: 5, repeatedValue: UIImageView())
```